# Reset Columns Section

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report with multiple columns section, like this:

**Column1**        **Column2**

In Column1, after changes in a special field, have the remaining rows show in Column2

Is there any way?

Comment: Do you mean you have checked the "Format with Multiple Columns" column checkbox for the detail section?  Or you simply have the same data value in two columns?

Answer (score 0):

From the menu,

1) Click on Report, Section Expert
2) Click DETAILS in Section Expert
3) Check Format with Multiple Columns